# $F$-linear basis for a cyclic submodule of $V_T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Consider $V$ a vector space over a field $F$ with dim$_F V = n \geq 1$ and let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map. Now suppose that $W$ is a cyclic submodule of the $F[x]$-module $V_T$, which is generated by some $v \in W$, and suppose that Ann$(v) = (f)$ where $f \in F[x]$ is monic of degree $k \geq 1$.

How might I go about proving that $v, T(v), \ldots, T^{k-1}(v)$ is an $F$-linear basis for $W$?  I'm kind of stuck to get started on this problem - would appreciate any help.

Comment: Suppose those vectors are dependent: then you get a polynomial satisfied by $T$ with degree smaller than $k$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you had a linear relation
$$a_0v+a_1T(v)+\dots +a_{k-1}T^{k-1}(v)=0,$$
it would mean the polynomial $\;g(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_{k-1}x^{k-1}$ belongs to $\operatorname{Ann}(v)$ and as it has degree less than  the generator degree of this ideal, $g(x)$ is the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: I see; so this clearly demonstrates linear independence - does spanning then follow from some sort of finiteness/dimensional argument?

Comment: Spanning results from $f(v)=0$, just like finiteness for an algebraic integer results from the existence of its minimal polynomial. A trivial induction shows that all $T^n(v)$ are  in the subspace generated by the first $T^i(v)\ (0\le i\le k-1)$.